# Check if a Plane ,formed by three 3D Points intersects a cube

Tags: c#, c++, 3d, geometry

I have a plane equation of form `a*x + b*y + c*z + d = 0`.

I have a cube centre (x1,y1,z1).

I want to check,if my plane intersects my cube.

One procedure,I tried is to ,find all the vertices of the cube.
Then,Substitute all the vertices in my plane equation.
Now,lets call all the values as S11,...S88.

`if((S11 > 0 && S22 > 0.........S88 > 0) || (S11 < 0 && S22 <0...S88<0)) then` --> My plane does not intersect the cube,Since all the vertices have same sign.

But,this is not really an optimized solution.I would like to know any other easy approach,which is feasible in in terms of computational cost.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think your solution is slow and expensive in terms of computational cost ?

Comment: Is the cube axis aligned? If not, do you have access to the rotation matrix of the cube?

Comment: @Michael Walz: If I have 1 lakh cubes to check, would n't that be costly? Because,for every cube,you need to retrieve 8 vertices and then check the sign convention.

Comment: What is _"1 lakh"_??

Comment: 1 lakh = 100,000

Comment: You are asking for a more performant solution without having given your solution implementation here. Compilers can be funny things and anticipating anything about emitted asm based on intuition is a good way to be wrong... A lot. Don’t optimize based on your gut, optimize based on the output of a performance analysis tool or benchmark

Comment: @loaner9: showing the code was premature, the formula needed to be discussed first.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a unit cube centered at the origin, `ax + by + cz` is maximized when the signs of `x, y, z` match those of `a, b, c` (to form three positive terms), and the maximum is `S = |a| + |b| + |c|`. The minimum is `- S = - |a| - |b| - |c|`.

So it suffices to check if `d` falls in the range `[-S, S]`.

If the cube is not centered at the origin, not unit or not axis aligned, you can apply an affine transform to make it so, and apply the same transform to the plane before performing the test.